# IntelliJ IDEA bold fonts after update to 14.1

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

on Ubuntu(12.04)
After update IDE to latest version(Build: 141.178.9) from 14.0

All fonts in menu\file names\contexmenu become BOLD

[image: ugly font]

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After playing with settings
I have rewrite default font, and set "*DejaVu Sans*" instead of "*Ubuntu*"

**Settings->Appearance**

[image]

Looks like before.

Comment: Great solution, I used "Ubuntu Light" font and it works as well

Comment: Is the __DejaVu Sans__ font [size 12] the default shipping font of Android Studio (Intellij IDEA) ? After all, what is the reason of fonts being bold?